# UPDATE INNER JOIN is taking so long then gives me a Lock Wait Timeout Exceeded Error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

code:

```
UPDATE movie_ratings a
INNER JOIN movie_years b ON a.imdb_title_id = b.imdb_title_id
SET a.year_ = b.year_
```

output:

```
Error Code: 1205. Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

I tried increasing both query timeout and lock wait timeout but still gives me the same error

I think it has to do with UPDATE statement , because I tried using INNER JOIN only and it works just fine

code:

```
SELECT a.imdb_title_id , b.year_ as year_ from movie_ratings a
INNER JOIN
movie_years b
ON a.imdb_title_id = b.imdb_title_id;
```

only took 0.031 secs

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the `imdb_title_id` columns indexed in both tables? How many rows are you updating?

Comment: Why do you have a `year` column in both tables, anyway? If the rating year is always the same as the movie year, you should store it in one place.

Comment: @Barmar no , they are not indexed. this is not my dataset , the owner did not have the year column in both tables so i am trying to put them in one place.

Comment: If they're not indexed in at least one of the tables, this has to do a quadratic scan.

Comment: @Barmar what do u mean by "quadratic scan"?

Comment: For every row in one table it has to scan the other table for all the matching rows. That's O(n^2)

Comment: @Barmar I get what you are saying now so do u think indexing will solve the problem? it's not that big of a dataset

Comment: @Barmar I will give it a try anyways , thx.

Comment: Actually, that error message suggests that some other process has the table locked, preventing updates. Is the database active when you try to do this?

Comment: @Barmar how do you check if the database is active? I am using MySQL workbench

Comment: @Barmar however I doubt that cuz i tried updating other columns, and it works just fine